# Bean Creation Exception. Injection of Autowired dependency failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble creating this bean in spring mvc and would really appreciate your help. Below is my Stack trace, Hbm file and Java class. Please let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!!!

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.controller.AppController.setShowtimeDAO(ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showtimeDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.controller.AppController.setShowtimeDAO(ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showtimeDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showtimeDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3409)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3398)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3386)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1731)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class ar.edu.uces.progweb2.pringmvc.model.Feature not found while looking for property: name
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeUsingReflection(SimpleValue.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createProperty(HbmBinder.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2122)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3406)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ar.edu.uces.progweb2.pringmvc.model.Feature
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:228)
    ... 72 more

jun 15, 2017 6:11:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.controller.AppController.setShowtimeDAO(ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showtimeDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.controller.AppController.setShowtimeDAO(ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showtimeDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showtimeDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.ShowtimeDAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3409)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3398)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3386)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1731)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class ar.edu.uces.progweb2.pringmvc.model.Feature not found while looking for property: name
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeUsingReflection(SimpleValue.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createProperty(HbmBinder.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2122)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3406)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ar.edu.uces.progweb2.pringmvc.model.Feature
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:228)
    ... 72 more
```

Hbm File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
<class name="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Showtime" table="showtime">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="dateAndTime" column="date_time"/>
    <many-to-one name="theater" 
        column="theater_id"
        not-null="true"
        cascade="none"/>  
    <many-to-one name="screen" 
        column="screen_id"
        not-null="true"
        cascade="none"/>
    <many-to-one name="feature" 
        column="feature_id"
        not-null="true"
        cascade="none"/>    
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Java Class

```
package ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Showtime {

    private int id;
    private Date dateAndTime;
    private Theater theater;
    private Screen screen;
    private Feature feature;



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getDateAndTime() {
        return dateAndTime;
    }
    public void setDateAndTime(Date dateAndTime) {
        this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
    }
    public Theater getTheater() {
        return theater;
    }
    public void setTheater(Theater theater) {
        this.theater = theater;
    }
    public Screen getScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        this.screen = screen;
    }
    public Feature getFeature() {
        return feature;
    }
    public void setFeature(Feature feature) {
        this.feature = feature;
    }
}
```

Comment: It cannot find a class: `ClassNotFoundException: ar.edu.uces.progweb2.pringmvc.model.Feature` - and for a good reason, you have a typo: `.pringmvc.` should probably be `.springmvc.`

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thank you!!! Did not see that :D. If you want to paste your comment and i'll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I doubt that your spring is not scanning your bean can you check your component scan for spring ? make sure it includes your package where ShowTimeDao exists. You can put @Component on class level for this class so that it will be managed by spring container.
2. Exception also complain parsing issue on mapping document make sure your spring context xml is accurate.
3. I think you ShowTime class needs a public constructor as well.
4. Can you please try package in hibernate-mapping element, also make sure that your hbm file is mapped in hibernate.cfg.xml

   .....

I am pasting a sample hbm file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="org.hibernate.tutorial.hbm">
    <class name="Event" table="EVENTS">
        <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE"/>
        <property name="title"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I had some issues in my mapping files. Thank you!